# Raw string in Python regular expression using Windows folder path

Tags: python, regex, string

Trying to use backslashes in raw strings with this regular expression:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]:\\.+(\\Data.+)', r'D:\folder\1', r'C:\Some\Path\Data\File.txt')
```

Expected output:

```
D:\folder\Data\File.txt
```

However `\f` is being interpreted. Is there any way to make this work without converting to forward slashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re.sub interprets escape sequences in the replacement string ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub)).  Adding an extra backslash before the \f to escape the backslash seems to do the trick:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]:\\.+(\\Data.+)', r'D:\\folder\1', r'C:\Some\Path\Data\File.txt')
```

If your replacement string is dynamic, you can always use another regexp to escape backslashes, or use str.encode('unicode-escape').

Comment: I guess that's escaping `\f`. Unfortunately for me the value before the `\1` is a variable.

Comment: You can always use another regexp to escape backslashes in the variable string.  str.encode('unicode-escape') might also be of some help.

Comment: Ah beautiful! This should work for any input. Thanks!! PS - you might want to add that to your answer :-)

Comment: Hmm found an escape method on the re object `re.escape(r'D:\folder') + r'\1'` but it outputs `D\:\\folder\1`. I have no idea why it's escaping the colon...

Comment: It escapes the colon because it is a non-alphanumeric character (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)), probably to avoid it being misinterpreted as a special regexp character.

Comment: Strange... A colon is a non-regex character.

Comment: It could be.  In POSIX regexps, [:punct:] represents a character class.  It also makes sense for consistency's sake.

Comment: Regexbuddy thinks that's just a character class... PowerShell doesn't escape it either `[regex]::Escape('D:\folder\1')` outputs expected `D:\\folder\\1`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid special characters translation you can use lambda-function:

```
print re.sub(r'^[a-zA-Z]:\\.+(\\Data.+)', lambda x: r'D:\\folder\1', r'C:\Some\Path\Data\File.txt')
```